# Mapping over array with deep nested json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first post and was extremely confused on how to map over the json data correctly.

The problem comes from when you map the user address property with Object.keys, everything is mapping over fine until it gets to the "geo" property values. What is the solution to map and render over every property easier?

```js
const style = {
  list: {
    listStyle: "none"
  }
};

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    username: "Bret",
    email: "Sincere@april.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kulas Light",
      suite: "Apt. 556",
      city: "Gwenborough",
      zipcode: "92998-3874",
      geo: {
        lat: "-37.3159",
        lng: "81.1496"
      }
    },
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    website: "hildegard.org",
    company: {
      name: "Romaguera-Crona",
      catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul style={style.list}>
        {data.map(user => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={user.id}>
              <li>{user.username}</li>
              <ul style={style.list}>
                {Object.keys(user.address).map(key => {
                  return (
                    <li>
                      {key} {user.address[key]}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: When doing an [mcve] for a React question, it's great to use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Okay much appreciated! Will keep be more mindful in my future posts.

Comment: `user.address[key]` will eventually return the `geo` object, and React doesn't render objects by itself.

Comment: ^ I already know this. Please be more constructive next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object keys on geo, in your `li` check if key is equal to geo, then map over it.

```
<li>
   {key} {key === 'geo' ? Object.keys(user.address[key]).map(geo => <i>{user.address[key][geo]}</i>) : user.address[key] }
</li>
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const style = {
  list: {
    listStyle: "none"
  }
};

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    username: "Bret",
    email: "Sincere@april.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kulas Light",
      suite: "Apt. 556",
      city: "Gwenborough",
      zipcode: "92998-3874",
      geo: {
        lat: "-37.3159",
        lng: "81.1496"
      }
    },
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    website: "hildegard.org",
    company: {
      name: "Romaguera-Crona",
      catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul style={style.list}>
        {data.map(user => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
              <li>{user.username}</li>
              <ul style={style.list}>
                {Object.keys(user.address).map(key => {
                  return (
                    <li>
                      {key} {key === 'geo' ? Object.keys(user.address[key]).map(geo => <i>{`${geo}: ${user.address[key][geo]} `}</i>) : user.address[key] }
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Ive been searching for hours for a case of this but could never find the correct syntax!!

Comment: @ReactDummy please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `if` statement for `geo` key and return your desired JSX.

```
{
  Object.keys(user.address).map(key => {
    if (key === "geo") {
      Object.keys(user.address[key]).map(geoKey => {
        return (
          <li>
            {geoKey} {user.address[key][geoKey]}
          </li>
        );
      });
    } else {
      return (
        <li>
          {key} {user.address[key]}
        </li>
      );
    }
  });
}
```